# Add page-link after post content. Before plugin

Tags: plugins

I want to add page-link before Facebook Comment plugin. Currently the sequence is:

1. Post content,
2. Facebook Comment,
3. Page link

In my `single.php`:

```
the_content();
wp_link_pages( array( 
    'before' => '<div class="page-link">'.__( 'Pages:', 'themejunkie' ),
    'after' => '</div>'
) );
```

In my plugin:

```
   add_filter ( 'the_content', 'fbcommentbox', 100 );
```

How to get the following order

```
 1. Post content,
 2. Page link,
 3. Facebook Comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Since FB comment box is within content, to add page link in between actual content and fb comment box, you have to add filter to content that runs before fbcomment filter does. you can do that by using  priority argument in [add_filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) function. You can set any number in priority that is lower to that set by fbcommentbox filter.

```
add_filter ( 'the_content', 'my_wp_link_pages', 98 );

function my_wp_link_pages($content){

$content.=wp_link_pages( array( 
    'before' => '<div class="page-link">'.__( 'Pages:', 'themejunkie' ),
    'after' => '</div>'
) );

  return $content;
}
```